# Camera on Galaxy Note 3 is sideways!

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I don't know what happens but the camera is sideways. No matter the way I hold the phone, it will always show the image and the resulting photo sideways. If I point to the computer screen right now for example, it will show me the basis of the screen pointed to the direction where the wall actually is

Comment: Have you flashed a custom ROM to the device, or is it running the stock firmware? Are you using the built-in camera app, or a third-party one? Has it always been this way, or did it work properly before?

Answer (score 3):

I had problems on my Samsung Note 2. Photos were being taken where I had to go into gallery and rotate right or left for image too be correct.

Just messed around with settings and fixed it by re-calibrating horizontal and vertical (I think). Hope this works for some of you.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 potential work arounds to try first:

- 1) Ensure screen rotate is turned on in the quick settings. Number 4 on pic below.

[image]

- 2) Reset your camera.

  ```
  a) Open Camera

  b) Click the Menu botton on the device

  c) Click the third tab (with the cog on it)

  d) Click 'Reset'
  ```

[image]

It is the third tab above. Click this guy: [image]

- 3) Download a third party camera.

Comment: Having to download a 3rd party camera would be pretty lame.  Hopefully options 1 or 2 from above are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my note 2. I put my phone in safe mode and here's the steps for that:

1. Power off the phone
2. then power it back on holding down the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button and the <kbd>power</kbd> button
3. once you see the samsung screen come on let go off the <kbd>power</kbd> button but continue to hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button.
4. When the phone boots back up then it should say "safe mode" in the bottom left corner.
5. When in safe mode check your camera and see if it works properly; if it does, the problem is an recently downloaded app.
6. Now take the battery out and power phone back up as usual to take it out of safe mode and check camera again; it should have reverted back to its normal settings. If not then you need to delete some apps and try to see what conflicting with your camera.

Good Luck it worked for me!!!

Comment: Tried this on a Note 3 and it worked. Step 6 consisted of just powering it back on; removing the battery was not necessary.